# Salesforce: how to obtain field API name from field Id?

Tags: apex, api

In Salesforce, is there a way to retrieve the field API name if I only know the field Id?

Example: I have a custom field on Opportunity called 'Order Number', with API name 'OrderNumber__c', and field Id '00Nf400000E82bW'.

Is there a way (without using the toolingAPI) to retrieve the field API name (OrderNumber__c) by only using the field Id (00Nf400000E82bW)?

I know how to get the field Id from the field API name (even without the toolingAPI) but not the other way around.

Comment: Check out the answers under [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41464/how-to-access-and-not-hardcode-the-field-id-for-a-custom-object-using-apex-to). Reversing the answer which uses a query on `FieldDefinition` seems like a good answer. Working on one now for kicks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Querying the `FieldDefinition` table seems to be the right move here.

```
SELECT Id, DeveloperName, DurableId 
FROM FieldDefinition 
WHERE DurableId = 'Lead.00NU0000004yMiU'
```

Only problem with this is that you need to prefix the object name to the field Id. Trying to use a `LIKE` filter (as below) causes this error:

```
WHERE DurableId LIKE '%00NU0000004yMiU'
```

> FieldDefinition: a filter on a reified column is required [EntityDefinitionId,DurableId]

Adding a filter on the `EntityDefId` while keeping the `LIKE` clause causes the same problem. I don't think this field supports that clause. Seems like to query this table, you'll need to know the object type by name.

Comment: ah, very useful -- a great technique to use when the web team looks at a webtolead or webtocase form and asks the sfdc admin - what field corresponds to `00NU0000004yMiU` because no one ever documented this on the W2L or W2C form.

Comment: `00NU0000004yMiU` is just an arbitrary field on the `Lead` object in the sandbox org I ran this on. I tested this with complex, standard, custom and lookup fields, this id is just the one i copied into the question.

Comment: Right.  I was just using it as an example too!

Comment: Wow, I really should't answer questions/comments before drinking my coffee ..

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who comes across this in mid 2019. I found the query selected here as best answer not working for me. What worked for me is using the following query from the Developer Console and clicking on the Tooling API checkbox:

```
select QualifiedApiName, DurableId from FieldDefinition where EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'Account'
```

That should give you all API names along with their IDs

Answer (score -1):

I misunderstood the question. Although the above answer is perfect, we have one more way to achieve this. We can use metadata API method `listMetadata()` (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_listmetadata.htm)

Comment: Didn't down-vote, but I don't think this code works. First issue (wouldn't run on my org until I fixed this) is that `getReferenceTo` can return a list, so you can't directly call a method on it, you need to loop over it. Second, a test run returned no values for a valid field id. Third, it seems like this would only return a value for a lookup field to `CustomFieldDefenition`, which isn't what the OP is looking for.