# URL Hack Not working

Tags: urlhacking

I have the following URL hack but it is not working any ideas?
The Asset.Account is a lookup field, is that the issue?

/02i/e?CF00NW0000000mpDu={!Asset.Account}&CF00NW0000000mpDu_lkid={!Asset.AccountId}

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it is not working?" Please be more specific.

Comment: check what the following fields are returning.  {!Asset.Account} , {!Asset.AccountId} by placing them in the alert. one more correction in your URL you closed } for Asset.Account twice. try to correct it. If this answers I post it as solution let me know.

Comment: Where is the button located? You are opening the Asset edit page, so this would mean that you have a button on Asset that tries to create a new Asset and puts the Asset.Account into some other custom lookup field?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like "{!Asset.Account}}" contains an extra "}".

Hope this is the issue.

Comment: Just a post copy issue there, no }} in my actual URL

Comment: Where are you trying to use the URL? Can you provide more details?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a URLENCODE of Asset.Account. It is not working because your account has a White Space, ',' that the Browser can't resolve.

Your correct URL is
`/02i/e?CF00NW0000000mpDu={!URLENCODE(Asset.Account)}&CF00NW0000000mpDu_lkid={!Asset.AccountId}`

Comment: Ok here is where I am with this now, I realized I needed to make some changes to my original ,  The Custom Object is Deployment, I wnt to populate the Account field when I create a new Asset record which is a related list on Deployment/02i/e?CF00NW0000000mpDu={!URLENCODE (Deployment__c.Account_Name__c)}&CF00NW0000000mpDu_lkid={!Deployment__c.Account_NameId__c}

Comment: you need create a cutom button in the asset object with your url => '/02i/e?CF00NW0000000mpDu={!URLENCODE (Deployment__c.Account_Name__c)}&CF00NW0000000mpDu_lkid={!Deployment__c.Account_Nam‌​eId__c}'. In the button you need specify that is a List button. 
After that you need modify deployment's page layout  => go related list => modify and add the new button.

Comment: Still having trouble the Account Field on the Assets does not populate from the Account field on Deployment when I create a new Asset record.

Answer (score 1):

Missed a '+' sign between the two field values. 
**It's always encouraged to pass the field id's dynamically to avoid problem when it's moved to production.**

```
var url="/02i/e?CF00NW0000000mpDu={!Asset.Account}"+"&CF00NW0000000mpDu_lkid={!Asset.AccountId}"
```

[Pass lookup field Id dynamically on button click](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/196403/pass-lookup-field-id-dynamically-on-button-click)

[How to get the entity ID for a custom field in Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17327/how-to-get-the-entity-id-for-a-custom-field-in-apex])[1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17327/how-to-get-the-entity-id-for-a-custom-field-in-apex)

Comment: You can find the difference and btw this is not from any dumps,
Ask further help from experts who are here judge the answer.