# Salesforce custom field id differ from org

Tags: managed-package

I am creating an app, that will be loaded into other orgs by a package. One of the functionalities is populate custom field value by using salesforce Id.The custom field would have a different id in every org... how can i place that salesforce id into the URL without knowing the actual id giving to it.

Please advise on this

Comment: What Id are your referring to, the field or a record ID. If Field ID maybe this will help: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17327/how-to-get-the-entity-id-for-a-custom-field-in-apex

Answer (score 0):

The field ID values do vary from org to org (as presumably they are allocated as each field is created) and a supported mechanism to obtain these IDs has not been provided by Salesforce. See [Apex describe information should also give Field ID's](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gM7mAAE) and vote for that too. That idea links to some of the hacks to work-around this missing mechanism.

The most conservative approach is to add a custom setting to hold the ID values and take them from there. But you then need to have a fairly technical person manually find the IDs after the app is installed and set them in the custom setting - far from ideal. You can also combine that custom setting approach with the tooling API call described in [How to get the entity ID for a custom field in Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17327/how-to-get-the-entity-id-for-a-custom-field-in-apex) (mentioned in Eric's comment) as the field ID only needs to be obtained once and can then be accessed from the custom setting thereafter.