# How to put in VF page a link to the full list of related records of a parent?

Tags: visualforce, related-list, describesobject, describefieldresult

I've seen that when a related list in a record's detail page surpasses 5 (or something) records, there is a link in the bottom that navigates to the full list of related records and nothing else.

In the instance I'm working on, I get this URL for such related list:
`<salesforce_url>/a0F?rlid=00N6100000HUcTH&id=a0BQ000000AwSvF`

By dissecting that URL I've found that `a0F` is the prefix of the related object (child of the relationship). `00N6100000HUcTH` is the id of the field definition in that object that relates it to its parent. And `a0BQ000000AwSvF` is the id of the parent itself: The record whose related list I wanna see.

How can I implement a link in a Visualforce page that gets me to this list in a way that works both in the sandbox and production? Do I have to build it manually or does Salesforce provide a shortcut? If I have to build it, does `Schema.DescribeFieldResult` have an Id field? Can't find documentation for that class.

Comment: find my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key prefix `a0F` can be achieved by this, replace `OBJECT_API_NAME` with your desired value.

```
OBJECT_API_NAME.sobjecttype.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix()
```

Following code will help you to getField() from relationship.

```
Schema.DescribeSobjectResult r = Account.SobjectType.getDescribe();
List<Schema.childRelationship> c = r.getChildRelationShips();

for(schema.childRelationship x:c){
    String name = ''+ x.getChildSObject();
    if(name.equals('Contact'))
    {   System.debug('getField=' + '' + x.getField());

    }

 }
```

And to get the Salesforce Id from field, refer this answer [How to get the entity ID for a custom field in Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17327/how-to-get-the-entity-id-for-a-custom-field-in-apex)

Hopefully, this will help you to achieve your functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the object name you can do it

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = CustomObject__c.sObjectType.getDescribe();
String keyPrefix = r.getKeyPrefix();
System.debug('Printing --'+keyPrefix );
```

Schema.DescribeFieldResult f = Schema.sObjectType.Custom_Object__c.fields.Custom_Field__c;
    System.debug(f.getRelationshipName());

and build your URL. Hope this helps.

Comment: How do you get the Id of the field? Does Schema.DescribeFieldResult have a id field? You show getRelationshipName, is it the same?

Comment: On VF controller you should have that value.